# Python3.3 type=file NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='blah blah')
parser.add_argument('reference_file', type=file, help='blah blah')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I run the above script I get the following error.

```
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

I don't know what's wrong. Is this not allowed in Python 3.3? Please help.

Comment: should it not be `type='file',` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file` was an alias for `open`, which has been removed in Python 3.

You can use `open` instead, but `argparse` has a better option: the [`FileType()` factory type]:

```
parser.add_argument('reference_file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='blah blah')
```

Comment: Great! Thanks very much! It doesn't seem too obvious from the documentation available with Python33 installation for Windows. Any good easy to read documentation available for Py33?