# PyPDF2, how to fix their example code to conform with Python 3

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am new to Python - I am using Python 3.4 but most of the online sample code I can find are for Python 2. In particular, the package I am trying to use, PyPDF2 has sample code:
https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/Sample_Code/basic_features.py
that is for Python 2. I can't seem to run it. I fixed the print part (line 7) to include brackets. What I don't know how to fix are lines 44 and 45, the ones where you actually save a pdf with the modifications made.  The relevant part of the code is:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("document1.pdf", "rb"))

output.addPage(input1.getPage(0))

outputStream = file("PyPDF2-output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
```

My Python doesn't understand file(). Gives an error to

```
outputStream = file("PyPDF2-output.pdf", "wb")
```

Any suggestions? Is there a library I should have imported to run this or is there a difference between Python 2 and 3 in how one writes this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16736833/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19499206/3001761

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 no longer allows you to open a file using the `file` constructor. Instead, use `open`.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the new `pypdf` docs: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Updating your specific example:

```py
from pydpf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

writer = PdfWriter()
reader = PdfReader("document1.pdf")

writer.add_page(reader.pages[0])

with open("PyPDF2-output.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```